# Étale morphisms and $G$-torsors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I first apologize for the silly question. I find it difficult to gain geometric interpretations from algebraic conditions in general.

Suppose $X$ is a scheme and $G$ is a finite group such that the quotient $\pi: X \rightarrow Y = X/G$ is well-defined. If $\pi$ is Étale at $x \in X$, i.e., $\pi$ is flat and unramified at $x$, is there any reason to imagine that there is a neighbourhood of $x$ where the restriction of $\pi$ gives a $G$-torsor?

For example, if $x$ is fixed under $G$, $\pi$ can be still unramified at $x$, right? Would the flatness on local rings $\mathscr{O}_{Y, \pi(x)} \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{X, x}$ restrict anything on the cardinality of the orbit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify what kind of quotient you are talking about, a categorical quotient? a good quotient? a geometric quotient? If the quotient is geometric, then your morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ is a principal bundle (See Mumford GIT chapter 0).  In other cases, you can choose an invertible $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ module $\mathcal{L}$ and a $G$-linearization on it, and restrict yourself to the open set of stable points by the action of $G$. In this open set, there exists a geometric quotient.

In other cases, it is no clear that you can find such a neighbourhood of $x$. You must find a $G$-invariant section of $\text{H}^{0}(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})$ for some $n>0$ such that $X_{s}=\{y\in X:s(y)\neq 0\}$ is affine, $x\in X_{s}$, the orbit of $x$ is closed and the dimension of the stabilizer group is zero (it is equivalent to be finite).